# Changing UI elements from another thread in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, delegates

I don't get it. If I want to change the text on a button from a thread other than the UI thread in Visual Basic .NET, I need to use a delegate, and do something along the lines of

```
 Private Delegate Sub SetTextDelegate(ByVal TheText As String)
 Private Sub delSetText(ByVal TheText As String)
     Button1.Text = TheText
 End Sub

 Private Sub ChangeText(ByVal TheText As String)
     If Button1.InvokeRequired Then
         Me.BeginInvoke(New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf delSetText), TheText)
     Else
         delSetText(TheText)
     End If
 End Sub
```

Of course I can make more generic functions that aren't so hard-wired. But still, it seems like a lot of typing. Am I doing this in a roundabout way? How is this not included in the control properties---why would anyone leave this up to the programmer if it is required?

Comment: This is the right way to do it. Cross-threaded operations are disabled because sharing data between threads is dangerous. This is why you create a delegate to marshal a call to the main thread which owns the control you're attempting to access. If you don't like creating a delegate for each call, you could very well write a generic wrapper of some kind to handle this functionality for you.

Comment: Like @Marc Gravell said you don't need the delSetText method, you can just use Button1.Text = TheText in the Else clause of ChangeText. Makes it a little less code.

Comment: I still don't understand why I must go through all this work for something that is always required. That is, if I'm changing the text of a button from another thread I *must* do this. So why even give the end user the option? Seems like the only time-saving way to do this is to create new classes inheriting from each control and override all the properties that need such delegates to be thread-safe. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Technically, it's not always required. You could disable this by setting CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls attribute to false on your control. However, this would generally imply that you're doing one of two things: you're debugging your code and don't want to run into this exception while you're doing so OR you're manually locking your shared resources.

Comment: By the way, I just saw this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx

It's probably a good habit to set this to true for all programs to avoid headaches later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, anonymous methods are very helpful here; perhaps there is something similar in VB? (my VB-fu is weak). You might also re-use the current method rather than have two; as an example:

```
void ChangeText(string text) {
    if(InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {ChangeText(text);});
    } else {
        Button1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Note that I've used `MethodInvoker` here deliberately - this is handled as a special case by `Invoke`, meaning it doesn't have to use the (very slow) `DynamicInvoke`.

I could also have done the `.Text = text` in the anon method, but that seems to violate DRY.

Comment: I should have switched to C# a long time ago. But VB is a hard habit to break. Thanks.